# python reverse guessing game different print messages

Tags: python

When I attempt to print a different message for there being more than one guess I am getting a double print message for when there is it is guessed in one iteration.

```
if guess >= 2:
    print ('Your number is %d. I found it in %d guesses.' % (guess, iteration))
if iteration == 1:
    print ('I found your number in 1 guess.')
```

> current output:
>       Enter two numbers, low then high.
>       low = 2
>       high = 8

```
Think of a number in the range 2 to 8.

Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to 4?
Type 'L', 'G', or 'E'): e

Your number is 4. I found it in 1 guesses.
I found your number in 1 guess.
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't defined what is "min_no" and "max_no" at first loop iteration in this line:

```
guess = guess_number(min_no, max_no)
```

And the last if is comparing the "guess" number instead of the "iteration" counter:

```
if guess == 1:
print ('I found your number in 1 guess.')
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I can't figure out how to get the program to print a different message for the program guessing the number in 1 guess vs. it guessing it in more than one guess.

You are checking the wrong value. Change this:

```
if guess == 1:
```

to:

```
if iteration == 1:
```

> 2. I need the program to give me a message about input being inconsistent when the user fails to respond to the less than/greater than prompts properly.

You are using an `else` in a situation where it can never be true, since `hint.lower()` is already certainly a valid letter, and you already checked all possible values. Adding an `else` to that is futile and not what you need. An inconsistency is detected when `min_no` becomes greater than `max_no`. So change:

```
else:
    raise ValueError('Your answers have not been consistent.')
```

to this:

```
if min_no > max_no:
    raise ValueError('Your answers have not been consistent.')
```

#### Other improvements

For getting a random integer between two integers, including both as possible outcomes, don't use `randrange`, but `randint`. Otherwise the second value will never be selected.

Your code will sometimes produce the same number as the previous guess, even if the user answered with `L` or `G`. This is because you keep that guess in the new range of possible values. So change:

```
max_no = guess
```

to this:

```
max_no = guess - 1
```

And also:

```
min_no = guess
```

to this:

```
min_no = guess + 1
```

Comment: thank you for your help, when I attempt the ValueError message is still not printing correctly: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Question.py", line 58, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Your answers have not been consistent.')
ValueError: Your answers have not been consistent.

Comment: What do you mean *does not print correctly*? That is how exceptions are printed, whether you raise them yourself (like here), or whether they are triggered by a native error. If you don't want that, then why do you use `raise`?